# Can I upload a binary wheel to a local devpi on Linux?

Tags: python, python-wheel, devpi

Is it possible to use "pip wheel" to upload a binary wheel on Linux, to a local devpi server?  Or do I need to get to a setup.py and do an upload from there?  It seems a shame to build the wheel without need of a setup.py (it's taken care of behind the scenes), only to need a setup.py to upload the result.

This makes me wonder:
C extensions
PyPI currently only allows uploading platform-specific wheels for Windows and Mac OS X. It is still useful to create wheels for these platforms, as it avoids the need for your users to compile the package when installing.

I'm doing `pip -v -v -v wheel numpy` (for example), and I have a `pip.conf` and `.pypirc` (both pointing at our local devpi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wound up using twine for the upload.  The devpi interfacing script ("devpi") is interesting, but I don't think we want it installed on all the boxes I'd need it on.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Try to use the `devpi upload` with the `--formats` option set to `bdist_wheel`:

```
$ devpi upload --formats bdist_wheel
```